# I need your help in List box actionscript3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

```
import fl.data.DataProvider;
import fl.controls.List;
var urlLoc:String = new String();
var dp:DataProvider = new DataProvider();
for (var i:uint = 1; i<=5; i++){
    dp.addItem( { label:"Channel" +i ,ben : "musicList"+i+".xml"}  );
}

var list:List = new List();
list.dataProvider = dp;
addChild(list);
list.setSize(140,60);
list.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, action);
function action(e:MouseEvent):void{
    urlLoc = e.target.data.ben;
    trace(urlLoc);
}
```

Its working fine and when I am click the down and up button its brings me an error.

"ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property data not found on fl.controls.BaseButton and there is no default value.
    at Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/action() "

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: I used EVENT.CHANGE instead of MouseEvent.CLICK. Its working well now. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U made a problem with listener Object.
Change the event Handler `Event.CHANGE` instead of "`MouseEvent.CLICK`".

```
list.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, action);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think List has a property data. I guess you want to get the selected item. please try:

```
urlLoc = e.target.selectedItem.ben;
```

Comment: I used EVENT.CHANGE instead of MouseEvent.CLICK. Its working well now. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the button event is bubbling though the List.  Do you want the event listener to fire on the up and down buttons or just on the list itself?

You could try:

```
function action(e:MouseEvent):void{
    if(evt.target is List) {
        urlLoc = e.target.data.ben;
        trace(urlLoc);
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't meet the error. but I can't able to trace the list values.